# R1C1-formulas in Gembox.Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

I am testing GemBox.Spreadsheet (47.0.1031) and found a note that R1C1-formulas are [available in the latest versions](https://support.gemboxsoftware.com/community/view/add-support-for-r1c1-formula-reference).

But, how does it work? My tests have failed so far:

```
SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
var f = new ExcelFile();
var ws = f.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
f.CalculationOptions.PrioritizeR1C1ReferencingNotation = true;

for(int i = 0; i<50; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[i, 0].Value = i + 1;
    ws.Cells[i, 1].Formula = "=RC[-1] * 17";
}
f.Save(..path..);
```

not even `=R1C1` works, and `=RC1` is read as an absolute reference (column RC row 1), despite my attempt with the `PrioritizeR1C1ReferencingNotation` setting.

Excel shows a warning about corrupted content in /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml-Part when opening the file and removes the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously, the R1C1 notation was only supported by the calculation engine.
Nevertheless, please try using the current latest [bugfix version](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/downloads/bugfixes.html) or [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GemBox.Spreadsheet/).

And try the following:

```cs
var ef = new ExcelFile();
var ws = ef.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[i, 0].Value = i + 1;
    ws.Cells[i, 1].FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1] * 17";
}

ef.Save("output.xlsx");
```